# Terminal warning or error

Tags: shell, perl

Every time i open up a terminal i do get the following message on the terminal

```
Can't locate local/lib.pm in @INC (you may need to install the local::lib module) (@INC contains: /home/punit/perl5/lib/perl5/x86_64-linux-thread-multi /home/punit/perl5/lib/perl5 /home/punit/anaconda3/lib/site_perl/5.26.2/x86_64-linux-thread-multi /home/punit/anaconda3/lib/site_perl/5.26.2 /home/punit/anaconda3/lib/5.26.2/x86_64-linux-thread-multi /home/punit/anaconda3/lib/5.26.2 .).
BEGIN failed--compilation aborted.
```

Is this thing need to be worried or it is just warning ?

How do i fix this?

Answer (score 2):

Your `.bashrc` or similar file had probably been edited to support [local::lib](http://p3rl.org/local::lib), but the environment has changed in the meantime. If you don't need `local::lib`, just remove the corresponding part, it should look something like

```
eval "$(perl -I$HOME/perl5/lib/perl5 -Mlocal::lib)"
```

If you need it, fix the path to it or reinstall it.

Comment: if i leave it like this? would it be a cause of concern

Comment: If you don't use Perl, you can leave it as is. But it's possible that a tool you use uses Perl under the hood and it might not work if you don't set local::lib properly.

Comment: i dont use perl much but i guess after i did something with conda this warning or issue started ..will try your instruction given above